# Update Check in Objective-C? Coming from C#

Tags: c#, objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm porting a program I wrote on C# to Cocoa and I'm trying to figure out how to use XML to go online to my website, grab the file and parse it, then compare the version and pop a message box to ask if you want to open your browser to the update page.

Here's the code from C#:

```
 public void CheckVersion()
    {
        Version newVersion = null;
        string url = "";
        string newfeatures = "";
        try
        {
            string xmlURL = "http://myurl.com/version.xml";
            XmlRead = new XmlTextReader(xmlURL);
            XmlRead.MoveToContent();
            string elementName = "";
            if ((XmlRead.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) &&
                (XmlRead.Name == "myProgram"))
            {
                while (XmlRead.Read())
                {
                    if (XmlRead.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                        elementName = XmlRead.Name;
                    else
                    {
                        if ((XmlRead.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) &&
                            (XmlRead.HasValue))
                        {
                            switch (elementName)
                            {
                                case "version":
                                    newVersion = new Version(XmlRead.Value);
                                    break;
                                case "url":
                                    url = XmlRead.Value;
                                    break;
                                case "newfeatures":
                                    newfeatures = XmlRead.Value;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to update checking server.");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (XmlRead != null) XmlRead.Close();
        }
        Version curVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
        if (curVersion.CompareTo(newVersion) < 0)
        {
            string title = "New Version Online";
            string question = "Download new version? \nmyProgram Version: " + newVersion.ToString();
            if (DialogResult.Yes ==
             MessageBox.Show(this, question + "\n\n" + newfeatures, title,
                             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                             MessageBoxIcon.Question))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
            }
        }  
    }
```

I'm pretty new to cocoa and most of that C# code was a snippet so any advice or help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: If your deploying on OSX then you should just use Sparkle - http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've been thinking about it, but honestly I think it's too much for such a simple application, this app is very small and I don't want to double or triple its size to add an update checking framework

Comment: Hector204: Sparkle is quite small. More than half of its size is the UI resources in the dozen or so languages that come with it. So, it's the same update checker you'd write, but a bit more powerful, already written, already (mostly) debugged, and already translated into a dozen or so languages. If you'd rather have that half a MB back, just rip out the languages you don't support.

Comment: I just gave it a try, and it was very easy to set up, thanks for recommending it, it works perfectly. Even better than I had ever hoped with this. I only support English so I guess I'll rip out those languages, thanks again!

Comment: Sparkle is the gold standard of the update system. Every Mac app should adopt it. All hail Andy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For updates the best solution available is Sparkle, as the others pointed out before.

But if you still want to know about loading XML from a server and parsing it you should read the documentation for the [URL Loading System](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html) and on [NSXMLDocument](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/NSXML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001269). With that it is not hard to get and parse the data, but you won’t be able to stuff everything into one method. `NSURLConnection` works with delegates so you don’t have to block the current thread while it is getting the data from the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yep sparkle worked perfectly, better than I had hoped. Coming from Windows I wasn't expecting it to be this easy. lol